# How come my elements are selectable anywhere on their line? How to fix?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a form and I can click the text boxes and submit button from anywhere on their line, not just the text box or the submit button itself.

Please help me, this is making me press things accidentally by clicking white space:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <label>
        <input type="file" name="file" class="custom-file-input">
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="theirname" type="text" placeholder="What's your name?">
    </label>
    <label>
        <button name="buttonname">Submit</button>
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe try posting something so we don't have to guess...

Comment: For text elements you have there `display: block` and for buttons `width: 100%;`.

Comment: your labels are wrapping your inputs.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your labels have been set to `display:block`- and as they are encapsulating your field controls, clicking anywhere on the row (as the label is 'taking up' the full width) will focus the control.

As such, change your code to change the labels to `display:inline-block` to stop taking up the 'full width' then using `br` to seperate each line in your `html`:

```css
label{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="">
    <label>
        <input type="file" name="file" class="custom-file-input">
    </label><br />
    <label>
        <input name="theirname" type="text" placeholder="What's your name?">
    </label><br />
    <label>
        <button name="buttonname">Submit</button>
    </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your labels are wrapping your inputs. Typically the label is what would allow you to select an input easier. A checkbox or radio button for instance. You click the text which is wrapped in a label and it will select the input associated with the label:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <label for="file">File</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" class="custom-file-input" id="file">
    <label for="theirname">Name</label>
    <input name="theirname" type="text" placeholder="What's your name?" id="theirname">
    <label for="submit">Submit</label>
    <button name="buttonname">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**EDIT** What you are intending (using CSS to float left and such). I am applying it to a div wrapper but you can apply it to the inputs only:

```css
    #float-my-boat input,
    #float-my-boat button {
     float: left;
     clear: both;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 5px 8px;
     font-size: 18px;
     color: #666;
     margin: 10px 0;
     border: 1px solid #CCC;
     border-radius: 6px;
     box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 4px #888;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="float-my-boat">
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="file" name="file" class="custom-file-input" id="file">
        <input name="theirname" type="text" placeholder="What's your name?" id="theirname">
        <button name="buttonname">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yeah ? If I use that then it won't look the same. I like the lay out of my current thing, I don't want to put random text above each one like there..

Comment: Then don't use labels. The labels are selectors for the inputs. Or at least don't wrap the inputs in labels.

Comment: What would you recommend instead? If I don't use labels all my stuff is in a big horizontal line.

Comment: Use a `<div>` or table rows

Comment: Would you recommend that I use a new div for each one or just a container for all of them? Please help me understand over here.

Comment: Yeah you can use a `<div>` per line. Just replace the `<label>` with `<div>` (as well as the close tags of course)

Comment: Ok.. I will take your word for it. But is this really the most optimized best way to do it? What would you do if you were doing it for yourself?

Comment: It depends on how rigid I want it to layout. Sometimes I use a table, sometimes a div. I will modify my answer and you can try it.

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer with what you are trying to do. Someone else posted an answer similar.

Comment: @pshahab48 - note. Per my answer which this now resembles, `br` is likely preferable to floating and clearing - not least due to providing semantic HTML.